# Word or expression for to describe the creation of a question

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I'm trying to find an active way of say something like "I was looking through the backlog and I acquired the following question". Perhaps a less casual way of saying "I was looking through the backlog and thought, 'wait, [question]'?

Comment: I formulated the following question.

Comment: "Wondered" seems good.

Comment: 'Came up with' is not unused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common AmE expression for this is:

"I was looking through the backlog when this question **occurred** to me ..."

> **OCCUR** *verb* (intransitive) --curs, --curring, --curred :
>
> **1**. to happen; take place; come to pass: "When did the accident *occur*?"
>
> **2**. to be met with or found; **present itself**; **appear**.
>
> **3**. **to suggest itself in thought**; **come to mind** (*usually followed by to*): 
>   "An idea *occurred* to me."
>
> from [**Dictionary.com**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/occurred)